# Red/green LEDs to indicate on/off

Tags: led, pnp

I am trying to build a circuit that drives a red LED when the relay is OFF and drives a green LED when the relay is ON. I found exactly what I was looking for, but it is for 9 V, and my circuit is designed on 24 V. I was hoping to get guidance/clarification on the resistor sizes when built for 24 V:

[Jim Dearden's design suggestion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/171804/61398) for 9 V:

[image]

So my question is about the resistors, especially the voltage divider. I am thinking it would be 3 kΩ and 50 for R2/R3. And 1.5 kΩ for R1 and R4 (to drive the LEDs at 15 mA). Do those values seem safe for my 2N3906 I just happen to have in the parts drawer? Would you please guide me in your thoughts as to using different values or a better transistor? I am just learning so thanks for the help!

If it matters, the relay coil is 24 V, 100 Ω and would be tied to the "power to circuit" label in his diagram.

Comment: Multiply all resistors values by around 2.5  and it should work.

Comment: I much prefer the circuit from Circuit fantasist in your link over the accepted solution. Just increasing the resistor to 4.7K to get appropriate LED currents at 24V.

Answer (score 1):

Normal small cheap LEDs have a forward voltage (Vf) of around 2 V (close enough for this discussion).  With the 9 V source in your link, that leaves 7 V across the 1 K resistors, for 7 mA LED current.

If you make zero changes to the circuit, then at 24 V the LED current will be 22 mA.  Most standard LEDs are characterized at 20 mA and rated to handle at least 30 mA continuously, so there is no explicit LED reason to make any changes.

However, at that current level R1 and R4 will be dissipating almost 1/2 W.  To be safe, you should use resistors rated for at least 1 W.

If you want to reduce the power dissipation, run the LEDs and bit more dim, save battery power, or whatever, increase R1 and R4 to 2.2 K.  This reduces the resistor power dissipation to a little under 1/4 W, so 1/2 W parts will be warm, but OK.

UPDATE:

The power dissipated in a resistance can be calculated with Joule's Law:

P = I^2 x R  (current-squared times resistance)

If you combine that with Ohm's Law and move things around, you get this:

P = E^2 / R  (voltage-squared divided by resistance)

Both of these equations can be re-arranged to solve for resistance given the other two values.  Note that E is the voltage across the resistance, not the LED.

R = P / I^2

R = E^2 / P

For improved long-term reliability, use a resistor rated for at least twice the expected power dissipation.

Comment: Thanks! What about the voltage divider? I thought I would have to change them to 3K and 50. Are you saying to leave them at the orig values? And how do I determine the power dissapated to know I am chosing a correct sized resistor? Thanks again!

Comment: If you are asking about R2 and R3, they are fine with the original values.

Comment: Thanks!  You even guessed where my confusion was in computing power!  I was astonished at the heat this will dissipate, as I used the 2v forward voltage of the LED and not the 24. Yikes,  it really is a wasteful circuit at 24v! thanks for the rule of thumb on wattage ratings,  too! Now off to the breadboard again!

Answer (score 1):

## Basic idea

Here is a minimalistic solution. It is based on the fact that:

- The voltage drops across the switch and the relay coil are inverse.
- The relay coil has a much lower resistance (100 Ω) than the LED-resistor network (1 kΩ).
- So the main trick here is ***to supply a high-resistance indicator through a low-resistance load by connecting it in parallel to the switch***. It is widely used to indicate the status of wall switches in the home.

The circuit topology looks like *two voltage dividers in parallel* or a *bridge circuit*.

## Operation

It would be nice to include meters, but the circuit would be cluttered and its "elegant simplicity" will lose its charm :-) So, it is better to use the *DC Live Simulation* by hovering the mouse over the circuit elements.

### Open switch

A low current flows through the top red LED1 and continues through the low-resistance coil; it is not enough to turn on the relay. A small part passes through the lower green LED2, but it is not enough for it to light up. Simply put, the coil shunts LED2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyEALW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Closed switch

Now the current flows through the closed switch SW (the top red LED1 is shunted). Then its main part continues through the low-resistance relay coil. The smaller part passes through the lower green LED2, and it lights up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZfyUW.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have your reasons for adding circuitry to invert the output of this relay, but I feel it should be said that you could select a different relay and use a double-throw one which would directly power the red LED when "power to circuit" is not energized.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with the transistor circuit these changes should work for 24 V. In the original circuit the values aren't exactly optimal, the base current was on the low side for saturation, so we'll address that as well as the voltage increase.

The LED currents run at around 7 mA, so we'll stick with that. That puts the current limiting resistors for 24 V at around 3k.

For saturation you want the base current to be around \$I_C/10\$, so for 7 mA that's 700 uA. With the switch open the base resistor will need to be
$$
\frac{24~V - 0.7~V}{700uA} = 33,285\Omega
$$
We're also going to have to account for a bit of current through R2, and we're going to reduce it's value a bit to get less leakage when the transistor is off, 4.7k should do. For R3 we want to use a bit less than 33k, I find 24k gives around 700 uA base current in simulation. I don't know what transistor you plan on, I've simulated with a 2N5401, it's rated at 150 V, 300 mA, 630 mW.

Here's the schematic with adjusted values.
[image: on/off indicator lights]

The LEDs will run at around 7 mA, the 3k resistors will dissipate around 160 mW so 1/4 W resistors should be okay. Transistor dissipates less than 1 mW, saturates well and leakage when off is under 10 nA.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate your time to explain your selection of how you tackled the voltage divider values by looking first at the Ic and woking it backwards. That really helped me understand! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbzYN1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a little bit more complex than Circuit fantasist's design because I've added a buffer transistor and a Schottky diode to tame the flyback, but I don't like the idea of maintaining almost 10% of the relay current when it is supposed to drop out. Some relays have a guaranteed drop-out that is considerably less than that, such as [this one](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/5662/AWHSH112D00G.pdf) that is not guaranteed to drop out until 5% of nominal voltage. There's also an issue with LED2 which would otherwise see a transient of more than -5V absolute maximum rating, if we leave the diode out (eg. 24V - 240mA x 1kΩ, or more than -200V). With my circuit, without the diode, the 240mA transient current would go through the E-C junction of the transistor, so it would be clamped, but that's not nice for the transistor, so the Schottky diode kills it completely.

Comment: Well, @Spehro, yours is a professional solution and mine is an amateur... but attractive with its simplicity :-)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist The explanation of yours is very nice, more than I can do.

Comment: The EB junction of the 2N3906 may still pass some flyback current; Veb is 0.5V, Vf for a 1N5819 is 0.6V.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, I tried to live up to your compliment :-) By the way, have you read [Don Lancaster's *Elegant Simplicity*](https://www.tinaja.com/glib/elesimp.pdf)?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I don't recall it offhand, but I'll take a look. I used to subscribe to Midnight Engineering.

Comment: @vir Yes, "completely" is hyperbole. There will still be some uA of forward B-C current. Even a 200mA 1N4148 will take most of the current, let alone a 1A Schottky.